# Binary array needs to have a fixed length

Tags: javascript, arrays, fixed-length-array

I'm currently working on a binary-encoder which, when finished, should check certain checkboxes based on the decimal number that's entered.

I already have the script for converting the number to an array.
An output for the number 512 would be `[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`, which is want I want.
But an output for the number 4 would currently be `[1, 0, 0]`, which I don't want to happen.

I want the array to have a fixed length, so the output for 4 should be `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]`

That's the code I currently have:

```
document.getElementById('myDez').oninput =
document.getElementById('myDez').onblur = document.getElementById('myDez').onkeydown = function (event) {  
    if (event.which == 13 || event.type == 'blur' || event.type == 'input') {
        var myDez = parseInt(this.value);
        var myBin = myDez.toString(2);
        document.getElementById('myBin').value = myBin;
        var arr = [,,,,];
        var arr =  myBin.split(''); 
        var numberArr = arr.map(Number); 

    }
    console.log(numberArr);

}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: At the end of the function, insert the additional 0 elements to make it the required size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `padStart(10, 0)` where 10 is the width you desire. Note that [`padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) will not truncate, so you can add `slice(-width)` if you want to ensure that large numbers don't exceed your desired width.

```js
console.log([...(+"42").toString(2).padStart(10, 0)].map(Number));
```

Usage:

```js
const decToBin = (n, width=10) => 
  (+n).toString(2).padStart(width, 0).slice(-width);

document.querySelector("input").addEventListener("keyup", e => {
  document.querySelector("div").textContent = decToBin(e.target.value);
});
```

```html
<input type="number">
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = new Array(10);
console.log(arr.length) // 10
```

That will create an array of fixed length.